# Apache + mod_python - can't configure server

Tags: ubuntu, django, apache-2.2, mod-python

I have got Ubuntu 10.04 (XEN) VPS. I want to set up Django server. I use apt-get to install django packages, apache, apache-mpm-prefork. Before using this configuration I saw "It works!" title, when I use ip/domain to get access to the server. After using configuration I saw:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

I found my django folder in this directory: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/ , while using find command to 'django-admin.py' (also, such file at /usr/local/bin) and put there folder from my development computer. So, this is my configuration:

```
<Location "/">
  SetHandler python-program
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE projectname.settings
  PythonDebug Off
  PythonAutoReload Off
  PythonPath "['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django','/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sidt-packages/django/bin/projectname'] + sys.path"
</Location>

<Location "/media/">
  SetHandler None
</Location>

<Location "/static/">
  SetHandler None
</Location>
```

What is wrong with my configuration? And how can I found information about errors, I can't understand what I must search to fix.

Comment: Check the Apache error log, which should be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` - that 500 error should be logging errors in that file.  Edit your question with interesting lines.

Comment: I thought python and mod_python debug isn't same thing. I enable it and got import error.

Comment: Fixed import error. Got 'template does not exist'. Also, I can get access to static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the Django project located?  You'll need to point your `PythonPath` at the project, not necessarily the Django library files.

It's configured to look in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sidt-packages/django/bin/projectname`; that should be "`site-packages`" instead, but confirm that that's where the project files are located (is "`projectname`" correct?).